# -flto flag segfault with gcc 5.1.0

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, memset

I am using gcc 5.1.0 on Windows.

When calling memset I am receiving a SEGFAULT, which does not occur when -flto flag (link time optimisation) is enabled.

```
/*#### function.h ####*/
void secure_bzero (void *s,size_t size);

/*##### function.c ####*/
/* Securely erase size bytes from s */
void WEAK __attribute__((noinline)) secure_bzero (void *s,size_t size) { 
     memset(s,0,size);
}
```

I noticed the segmentation fault, when I wanted to debug my application in CodeBlocks. I enabled the debugging symbols flag (-g) and got warned that Combining -flto with -g is *"currently experimental and expected to produce wrong results."*

I don't understand how the segmentation fault is produced here.

thanks to Eugene Sh. hint to post a complete example:

```
#include "function.h"
int main(){
    unsigned char seed[32];
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++){
        seed[i] = i;
    }
    secure_bzero(seed,sizeof(seed));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It is not "produced here". In order to segfault a program has to have at least some `main`. And likely it is completely unrelated to the flags.

Comment: Not the answer, but GCC 5.1 is *old*. You should download latest MinGW-w64, it has GCC 8.1...

Comment: Show `randombytes`.

Comment: i just installed the newest version of CodeBlocks and thats the compiler which came with it...

Comment: @Eugene Sh., randombytes are some lines more, but randombytes works. it outputs n random numbers. the segfault occurs in secure_bzero.

Comment: Please, show `randombytes`. It is a part of [mcve].

Comment: Ok, so `randombytes` is complex. And is not sufficient for [mcve]. How about you replace it with something simple and try reproducing the problem (like simply fill the array with some predefined values? Or if you insist, use `rand`)?

Comment: same error, see update

Comment: Good, at least now we can say that your code is OK, if you are actually compiling and running it with the stated error..

Comment: Why are you defining `secure_bzero` as `WEAK`? Could it be that it is linking with some other `secure_bzero`?

Comment: I can't compile secure_bzero()

Comment: @EugeneSh., the WEAK is likely used here to inhibit compiler optimizations, so that the function is always called and the compiler will not use its knowledge of the function body.

Comment: @jonnyx, does the segmentation fault go away with `-flto`, or is it introduced by it? Is this an embedded target with a custom `memset`?

Comment: just doing memset directly works, but the code is not produced by me but from a NIST PQ algorithm which I need to investigate for my thesis. So I don't really know why it is defined as WEAK; just interessted where the segfault comes from. The code works anyways, I am just curious :)

Comment: @Florian Weimer, segfault goes away with -flto. currently it is just being debugged in codeblocks on windows, but i am up to implement it on a tricore from infineon

Comment: Why is this tagged [embedded] if you are running on Windows?  If Windows is simply your development host, then that information is mostly irrelevant if the segfault is a runtime error in your running code rather then occuring ar build time.

Comment: sorry about that, thought it might also be relevant for my implementation on the tricore.